# Close browser after oauth-redirect to app

Tags: android, android-intent, oauth

I am starting an intent to launch a browser for oauth-login.

```
String url = authUrl+"?response_type=code&client_id="+oauthSettings.getClientId()+"&state="+state+"&redirect_uri="+ Const.oauthRedirectURL;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
```

After the user is successfully logged in, an activity of my app is launched to handle the oauth redirect. If everything was ok, the users can use my app until they close it. After closing the app, the browser with the authentication-url is visible to the user and has to be closed manually. If the user refreshes the browserpage, a new auth-redirect will be started and my app is launched to handle it.

My question: Can my app force the browser to close itself after the redirect-intent is handled by my app?

Comment: have you got any solution i also need to close browser when we redirect to our application

Comment: I am using a webview now so I have full control of the process

Comment: I also try the same approach but when I'm loading my URL in webview it shows error like available err_name_not_resolved